# Extracting data from XML source using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml file with over 30k entries.  The Idea is to search by lifenumber and create tables based off of the info associated with that person's data.  For some reason the main source 'Person' does not link to a sub source underneath 'Appointment'.  I am unable to figure out how to link these. I was able to create two functions to pull each set.  But I am coming up short trying to link both into one function.  Where I am able to query lifenumber and pull both the Person/appointment data together.

Sample of Source Data: (Create a test xml in the exact format below)

```
  <Person lifenumber="21596" lname="LOVER" mname="J" fname="JERRY" affiliation="Hospital One" email="jerry.LOVER@mss.edu" building="" floor="" room="" phone="" hrstatus="A" active_direct_user="lassej04" active_direct_provider="HOSPITAL">
    <Appointment affiliation="Hospital One" deptname="Cardiology" divname="" deptcode="821" title="ASST CLIN PROF"/>
  </Person>
  <Person lifenumber="27901" lname="WINNER" mname="" fname="KURT" affiliation="Hospital One" email="kurt.WINNER@mss.edu" building="Annenberg" floor="17 TH FL" room="17-44" phone="(212) 241-1234" hrstatus="A" active_direct_user="hirsck01" active_direct_provider="MSSMCAMPUS">
    <Appointment affiliation="Hospital One" deptname="Pediatrics" divname="" deptcode="852" title="PROF LECTR"/>
  </Person>
  <Person lifenumber="30899" lname="OLYMPIA" mname="R" fname="MARTIN" affiliation="Hospital One" email="martin.OLYMPIA@mss.edu" building="" floor="" room="" phone="" hrstatus="A" active_direct_user="gellem03" active_direct_provider="HOSPITAL">
    <Appointment affiliation="Hospital One" deptname="Neurology" divname="" deptcode="841" title="ASSOC CLN PROF"/>
    <Appointment affiliation="Hospital One" deptname="Neurology" divname="" deptcode="105" title="ASSOC ATTN"/>
  </Person>
  <Person lifenumber="31183" lname="SCOOBY" mname="" fname="JAMES" affiliation="Hospital Two" email="" building="" floor="" room="" phone="" hrstatus="A" active_direct_user="" active_direct_provider="">
    <Appointment affiliation="Elmhurst/Queens Hospital" deptname="Otolaryngology" divname="" deptcode="A35" title="O.R. TECH"/>
  </Person>


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Functions BUILT BELOW

$xmlPath = 'C:\Scripts\source.xml'
[xml]$data = Get-Content $xmlPath

#pulls everything above 'Appointment"
function Search-LifeNumber 
{
    param(
        $Source = $data,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        Position=0)]
        $LifeNumber

    )

    $Target = $Source.People.Person | ? {$_.LifeNumber -eq $LifeNumber} 

    return $Target
}
#pulls Deptment Code data associated with targeted node
function Search-ByDepartmentCode 
{
    param(
        $Source = $data,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            Position=0)]
        $DepartmentCode

    )

    $Target = $Source.SelectNodes('//People/Person/Appointment') | ? {$_.deptcode -eq $DepartmentCode} 

    return $Target
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the XML based on attribute values. Use XPath syntax `/path/to/node[@attribute="value"]`. Like so,

```
[xml]$p = get-content c:\temp\people.xml

# Search by Appointment at deptcode A35
$nl = $p.SelectNodes('/People/Person/Appointment[@deptcode="A35"]')
# How many results?
$nl.Count 
1
# Check the deptname
$nl[0].deptname
Otolaryngology
# Check the parent node's affliation?
$nl[0].parentnode.affiliation
Hospital Two


# Search by lifenumber
$nl = $p.SelectNodes('/People/Person[@lifenumber="30899"]')
# Check the email
$nl.email
martin.OLYMPIA@mss.edu
# How many appointments?
$nl.appointment.count
2
# See the titles
$nl.appointment | % { $_.title }
ASSOC CLN PROF
ASSOC ATTN
```

Comment: vonPryz,Thanks!  this was part 1.. part 2 I will now work on is creating an output of this data.  The XML file has over 30k entries.  I have a list of 1k lifenumbers which I need to pull Name/email/deptcode.   This definitely cleared up some of the hurdle I was having.

Comment: @DwayneC No problem. Check the Accept tick if this solves the selecting part. Please post a new question about how to format output; you should include modified code and sample output there too. If you edit those into the current question, it's going to get confusing.

Comment: Sorry about this.  I did not realize I didn't accept this answer. My apologies