# Extracting data from XML source using powershell Part II - Pulling data from a CSV to use against a particular field or function

Tags: xml, powershell

So two scenarios:
Sample of Data Source:

```
<Person lifenumber="21596" lname="LOVER" mname="J" fname="JERRY" affiliation="Hospital One" email="jerry.LOVER@mss.edu" building="" floor="" room="" phone="" hrstatus="A" active_direct_user="lassej04" active_direct_provider="HOSPITAL">
<Appointment affiliation="Hospital One" deptname="Cardiology" divname="" deptcode="821" title="ASST CLIN PROF"/>
```

---

Code Used (with Functions)

```
$xmlPath = 'C:\Scripts\source.xml'
[xml]$data = Get-Content $xmlPath

#pulls everything above 'Appointment"
function Search-LifeNumber 
{
    param(
        $Source = $data,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        Position=0)]
        $LifeNumber

    )

    $Target = $Source.People.Person | ? {$_.LifeNumber -eq $LifeNumber} 

    return $Target
}
#pulls Deptment Code data associated with targeted node
function Search-ByDepartmentCode 
{
    param(
        $Source = $data,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            Position=0)]
        $DepartmentCode

    )

    $Target = $Source.SelectNodes('//People/Person/Appointment') | ? {$_.deptcode -eq $DepartmentCode} 

    return $Target
}
```

How would I be able to use a csv containing a list of lifenumbers to run against the function? To pull all data associated to that life number under //People/Person?

---

I'll add the other code example in another posting.

Comment: Sample Source from this link is better. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328661/extracting-data-from-xml-source-using-powershell?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You should [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) given in the other question if it solves that part of your problem. That will encourage someone to help you here, too.

Comment: I thought I did.  Let me go back. Thanks for letting me know Fission